# redirect folder to external website

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect a subfolder in a subdomain to an external link with htaccess.

example:

test.mydomain.com/subfolder would redirect to http://www.stackoverflow.com.

The subdomain 'test' doesn't exist. It should be no problem because I've done something like this before. only not with a subfolder.

this htaccess works:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://stackoverflow.com
```

this doesn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(subfolder/.*)$ http://www.stackoverflow.com/
```

There need to be 4 subfolders wich redirect to differend external pages. how can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Your reges is little off and expects a slash after folder name. Try this as **your very first rule:** in the root .htaccess of test domain:

RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^subfolder(/.*)?$ http://www.stackoverflow.com/? [NC,L,R=302]
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. also the link i'm trying to include ends with .ics. i don't think ist good to have a /? after that.

Comment: Question has no mention of `.ics`. Anyway what is the full URL that you tried and didn't work for you?

Comment: The full url is this: https://www.google.com/calendar/ical/c313lstuuivbrgmgo4dllgp9a8%40group.calendar.google.com/public/basic.ics. also if i try to redirect to stackoverflow it doesn't to enything. the server gives a: no page found.